# convert hdf5 file to grayscale

Tags: julia, hdf5

How do I convert a .h5 file to grayscale in Julia?

I tried this

```
img = stack[:,:,100] #just some hdf5 file
img = convert(Image{Images.Gray}, img)
```

I get this error:

```
LoadError: PyError (:PyObject_Call) <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
TypeError(u'Image data can not convert to float',)
```

Comment: Could you post a fuller working example of your code?  For instance, I'm guessing that you're using one or more packages here, but it's not clear which ones.  It's also not clear how your object `stack` was created / loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're also `using` some other package that defines `Image`, and this conflicts with the definition in `Images.jl`. Let's imagine that other package is called `PythonImage`. Try it like this:

```
using Colors   # that way you don't have to say `Images.Gray`
import PythonImage, Images  # `import` rather than `using` prevents conflicts

imgg = convert(Images.Image{Gray}, img)

# ...if you need the other one, use `PythonImage.Image`
```

Or you can `using Images` and `import PythonImage` (or vice versa). The only thing you can't do is `using` for both of them and expect everything to work.